# Prove that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x=\infty$ (proof check)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Can someone check if my proof is correct? Much appreciated!

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in $(0,\infty)$ such that $x_n\to 0$. Suppose $f(x_n)\to L$ for some real number $L$. We may assume $L\geq0$ since $f\big((0,\infty)\big)=(0,\infty)$. Then there exists some $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ where $n>N_1\implies |f(x_n)-L|<\frac{L}2$.

Since $x_n\to 0$ there exists some $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N\implies x_n<\frac1{2L+1}$, hence for $n>max(N_1,N_2)$, we have
$$2L+1<f(x_n)\leq|f(x_n)-L|+|L|<\frac{L}2+L=\frac{3L}2$$
a contradiction.

EDIT: Continuity is given.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $(f(x_n)) \to L$ and then showing such $L$ is impossible doesn't leads to conclude that $(f(x_n)) \to \infty$.From here we can say either limit doesn't exists or if exists then not finite.

For an example $x_n=(-1) ^n$ , then $x_n\to L\in \Bbb{R}$ is impossible but that doesn't mean $x_n\to \infty$

---

If you want to prove using sequence , then...

$(x_n)\subset (0,\infty) $

$x_n\to 0$ implies $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in \Bbb{N} $ such that $|x_n|<\epsilon $ for all $n\ge  \Bbb{N}$

Then $|f(x_n) |=|\frac{1}{x_n}|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for all $n\ge \Bbb{N}$ implies $(f(x_n)) \to +\infty$

Answer (score 1):

You showed that the sequence $f(x_n)$ is not convergent, however, that does not imply that $f(x_n)\to \infty$. For example the sequence defined by $x_{2n-1}=1\ $ y $\ x_{2n}=-1\ $  is not convergent, but $x_n\not \to \infty.$
$f(x_n)\to \infty$, if for all $A>0$, exist $N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N_1\implies f(x_n)>A$. I suggest you use the archimedean property.